# Wrong return type when calling function from dll in Python

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

I have function in DLL and try to call it in Python 3. Function prototype is:

```
__declspec(dllexport) char* getmetadata(char* szFile, size_t* metadata_size);
```

Python code is:

```
...
libm = ctypes.CDLL("libm.dll")
fc = libm.getmetadata
fc.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
fc.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_size_t)]
size = ctypes.c_size_t(0)
buffer = fc(bytes(path, "utf8"), ctypes.byref(size))
```

Type of buffer is bytes. Why it is not c_char_p?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ctypes` converts `c_char_p` to Python's native bytes type automatically.  It's a convenience:

```
from ctypes import *
dll = CDLL('msvcrt')
dll._getcwd.argtypes = c_char_p,c_int
dll._getcwd.restype = c_char_p
out = create_string_buffer(30)
print(dll._getcwd(out,30))
```

Output:

```
b'C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop'
```

But use something besides `c_char_p` and you will get a `ctypes` object:

```
dll._getcwd.restype = POINTER(c_byte)
result = dll._getcwd(out,30)
print(result)
print(string_at(result))
```

Output:

```
<__main__.LP_c_byte object at 0x0000000002C81248>
b'C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop'
```